# How to switch off blue overlay in iphone chrome emulator?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, android-emulator

When I'm doing a long click in iphone crhome emulator, I'm getting blue overlay on the whole screen. Is it possible to switch off this overlay, or make it transparent?[image]

Comment: You just have to click on another line on the right side... or move your mouse. This blue overlay help you to see which `div` you are selecting.

Comment: As far as I know or Google is saying me, there is no possible way. But there is a way with Chromium, you can actually change the whole lay-out included the highlighting colors.

Comment: > You just have to click on another line on the right side... or move your mouse. This blue overlay help you to see which div you are selecting

No, I'm getting another overlay, making a long click in some place of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);` helped me